# Bootstrap modal selecting wrong item with jQuery Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

When I trigger this bootstrap modal it selects the topmost entry in the table as e.entry and not the entry on the row. If I sort the column, the modal will again pick the topmost entry.

Any ideas as to what might be the issue?

Thanks!

```
                <script >
                $(document).ready(function(){
                   $("#EntryTable").tablesorter(
                    {sortList: [[1,0]]}
                    );
                 });
            </script>
            <table class="table" id="EntryTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                                
                        <th>Idea</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


            {% for e in projects.entries.all %}
            <tr class="info">
                <td>{{ e.entry }}</td>
                <td><a href="#EditModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="open-EditEntryDialog label label-info" data-id="{{ e.entry }}">Edit</a>

                    <div class="modal hide fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3 id="EditModalLabel">Edit an Entry</h3>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="{{ projects.get_absolute_url }}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type='hidden' name='entry_id' value='{{ e.id }}'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='project_id' value='{{ projects.id }}'>
                            <input type='text' id='entry' name="entry" placeholder="{{ e.entry }}"> 

                        </div>

                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        <button type='submit' name="edit_entry" value='Edit Entry' class="btn btn-primary">Edit Entry</button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: One thing I immediately notice is that you have DIVs that are improperly opened/closed in or around your FORM...that alone might make tablesorter choke. And where's the rest of your table code?

Comment: @technoTarek Sure, I'll try to set up a jsfiddle, though it won't be exactly the same without the django stuff. The DIV is placed that way so I can use the footer buttons as my form buttons.

Comment: you cannot intersect <form> and <div> tags, move that </form> out of that footer <div>, put it within the modal <div>, what you are doing right now is plain wrong in terms of valid HTML structures. Of course you'd also  have to move the opening <form> tag into modal <div>.

Comment: That's one benefit of the fiddle--that you will be removing the Django code and thereby narrowing down on whether it's a server- or client-side problem. You should just be able to take your rendered source code for purposes of making your fiddle...But as I said, and 16dots reiterated, you need to make your code valid first.

Comment: Still making adjustments (the modal isn't popping up) but here it is @technoTarek http://jsfiddle.net/craigcannon/TEG6B/17/

Comment: Your markup still isn't valid. Table sorter will not work as long as you're improperly mixing up your FORM and DIV tags...

Comment: Not updated in the Fiddle above...Also, as a measure of good Stack Overflow citizenry (and good debugging generally), could you clean up the fiddle? Remove all unnecessary code (everything outside of the table including the navbar), all inline styling, all extraneous css/js (eg., the dropdown js and responsive cs), etc etc. Basically, boil it down to only the components in question.

Comment: @technoTarek sure thing! here's simplified version, though I seem to have broken the modal... http://jsfiddle.net/craigcannon/TEG6B/21/

Comment: @CraigCannon The modal is broken because you loaded the wrong version of Jquery. You had 1.6.2 , .on() was added in 1.7

Comment: @16dots thanks! I have a newer version running on my computer. I think the issue has to do with calling the modal from a for loop. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working, forked fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/9KsxW/4/

Important: The reason your modals stopped working is because you (1) had the wrong version of jQuery loaded and (2) have multiple elements in the DOM with the exact same ID (e.g., #EditModal). IDs are supposed to be unique. When you have multiple elements with the same ID, the modal plugin doesn't know which elements to interact with. For the purposes of the fiddle, I simply made the IDs #EditModal, #EditModal2, and #EditModal3. Obviously, you'll want to do that dynamically with your server-side code.

On a related note, I also removed some of your javascript. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish with the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditEntryDialog", function() {
    var EntryId = $(this).data('id');
    console.log($(this));
    $(".modal-body #entry").val(EntryId);
    $('#EditModal').modal('show');
});​
```

...but it was making the modals behave improperly. It was launching all three modals instead of just the selected one. Again, it may be because of your loose use of IDs and classes--that is, you're not using the correct selectors to select the exact/right element.

In any case, you'll see the fiddle now sorts and launches the correct modal (I changed the title of each modal to help confirm that fact).

Comment: Thanks! Though there's still an issue. The modals are generated by a for loop and that's how they ended up with the same name. What's the preferred way to handle this? Oh, and that bit of javascript is so the correct entry appears in the modal text field.

Comment: Regarding the loop, you could simply iterate a counter variable and append its current value to each ID. I'm not a python/django coder, but in PHP it would be something like: $i=0; foreach{ $elementID = 'EditModal' . $i; $i++ }.